# Rails Postgre datetime saving as nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, datetime

I'm trying to save a datetime field on my model. I saves correctly, but when I fetch the record, its value is nil. I'm using Rails 4.2.4 with postgresql. Example:

```
2.2.2 :006 > Post.create(data_agendada: DateTime.now)

   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("data_agendada", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["data_agendada", "2016-01-31 17:45:42.895390"], ["created_at", "2016-01-31 17:45:42.897885"], ["updated_at", "2016-01-31 17:45:42.897885"]]

Sun, 31 Jan 2016 17:45:42 BRST -02:00
   (34.5ms)  COMMIT

Post id: 71, cod: nil, data: nil, legenda: nil, created_at: "2016-01-31 19:45:42", updated_at: "2016-01-31 19:45:42", tags: nil, facebook: nil, twitter: nil, instagram: nil, app: nil, materia_id: nil, shares_count: nil, fonte_id: nil, user_id: nil, likes_count: nil, data_agendada: "2016-01-31 19:45:42"

2.2.2 :007 > Post.last

Post id: 71, cod: nil, data: nil, legenda: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, tags: nil, facebook: nil, twitter: nil, instagram: nil, app: nil, materia_id: nil, shares_count: nil, fonte_id: nil, user_id: nil, likes_count: nil, data_agendada: nil
```

Does anyone know what's the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Can you do this: 1) test = Post.new(data_agendada: DateTime.now); 2) test.valid?; (3) test.errors

Comment: or rather the output of `Post.create!(data_agendada: DateTime.now)`

Comment: Here's the output:

2.2.2 :004 > test.valid?
 => true 
2.2.2 :005 > test.errors
 => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x000000054a27e8 @base=#<Post id: nil, cod: nil, data: nil, legenda: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, tags: nil, facebook: nil, twitter: nil, instagram: nil, app: nil, materia_id: nil, shares_count: nil, fonte_id: nil, user_id: nil, likes_count: nil, data_agendada: "2016-01-31 22:17:17">, @messages={}>

Comment: And for Post.create!:


and for Post.create!:

 => #<Post id: 75, cod: nil, data: nil, legenda: nil, created_at: "2016-01-31 22:18:42", updated_at: "2016-01-31 22:18:42", tags: nil, facebook: nil, twitter: nil, instagram: nil, app: nil, materia_id: nil, shares_count: nil, fonte_id: nil, user_id: nil, likes_count: nil, data_agendada: "2016-01-31 22:18:42"> 

Looks like its saving correctly, but when I fetch the record, the value stored is null. I also tried to execute the sql on postgre console, but I also got the same result. Saving date is ok. It only happens for datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this can happen with datetime fields if your default timezone is set incorrectly. Check out this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20487) for more info.

Your `application.rb` should have a time zone from `rake time:zones:all` (or none at all).

```
config.time_zone = "Brasilia"
```

Comment: guess time zone is configured properly:

config.time_zone = 'Brasilia'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Brasilia'

Comment: Maybe try removing them, restarting your console and seeing if it works then. If it does, then the problem would be related to that part. Otherwise I'll look for other possible problems

Comment: Already restarted console, computer and everything else. Also tried create a test model with only one datetime field... It also ocurrs the same problem, so guess may be some problem at postgre, I guess.

Comment: Did you remove the timezone config, type `exit` in `rails c`, and then `rails c`, `Post.last`?

Comment: Thanks! That works! But what was wrong on my configuration?

Comment: That what we have to figure out now, in my `application.rb` I have `config.time_zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"`. Maybe try that and restart like before. If that works, then try `config.time_zone = "Brasilia"` and restart. Let me know where it goes wrong

Comment: Tried that and now it works for 'Brasilia' too. Don't understand what happened. Thanks, anyway!